# How to invoke another view when the iPhone is on landscape

Tags: iphone, ios

![Second View its the main gallery view][1]
Hello I`m trying to invoke a new view controller when the device is on landscape orientation. It's an image gallery with scroll view, the thing is I want to show the image gallery on a different position but I don't know how. I'm using Xcode 4.3 with Story boards so its a bit different then the older version I think.

Thank you for your help.
![This how it looks without the code in landscape, the scroll dissapears][2] Thats why I'm calling another view

Dang! I'm not allowed to post images

Comment: Are you using the same view controller but two instances of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your landscape view in the storyboard. Add an identifier, like LandscapeView, in the inspector. Then, in your original view controller, import the header file of the view controller of the landscape view:

```
#import "LandscapeViewController.h" //Change to whatever your file is called
```

and modify the following method like so:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    LandscapeViewController *landscapeView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LandscapeView"]; //change LandscapeViewController to the correct name and change LandscapeView to the correct identifier
    landscapeView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve; //Or whatever transition you want

    [self presentModalViewController:landscapeView animated:NO];
    return YES;
}
```

Then, in the view controller of the landscape view, modify the same method as follows:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: So I need to create a new class for the Landscape view controller?

Comment: settingsView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;   ------ This line sends me an Error says : "Undeclared Identifier "settingsView"  I need to declared in LandscapeViewController.h ?

Comment: @user1426865 Sorry, it should be landscapeView. I copied and pasted this from one of my apps and forgot to change that. I'll edit it in my answer now.

Comment: ok now its working but when I get back to the portrait view the tab bar is gone. I tried using : self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO; 
But still isn't showing anything.

Comment: @user1426865 Is there a tab bar in the portrait view, landscape view, or both?

Comment: Its a Tab bar project in the second view I made the Gallery the second view its a portrait, the landscape its now working with the code you gave me but when I turn the device in portrait it shows the second view without the tab bar

Comment: @user1426865 Does the app start in portrait or landscape? In my answer, I'm assuming it starts in portrait. I can change it if it starts in landscape...

Comment: Won't this cause problems if someone flips from one landscape view to another landscape view, like flips their device around from one side to the other quickly?  From `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft` to `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight` without entering portrait mode for instance.  I would add a check to which mode it is trying to enter when the method is called.

Comment: @JustinPaulson When flipping the device from 'UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft' to 'UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight', does the device enter portrait at all? After all, it **is** in the portrait orientation, albeit only for a split second. If the device doesn't register being in portrait mode, then you are right, it will cause a problem.

Comment: No it does not have to enter portrait mode.  You can hold it on the right, then rotate it to where it is on the left without ever holding it in portrait mode.  Try it on a device, you will see.  You can't do it in the simulator, but when it is in your hand you don't have to rotate to portrait to flip which side is up and which side is down, you can just flip the device over without rotating it.  And if someone happens to do that then your views will be switched where your landscape will be in portrait and your portrait in landscape.  I'd just add some checks and then your solution will work.

Comment: @JustinPaulson I don't have a membership to the Developer Program yet - I'm only testing on the simulator. This is easy to fix, though - instead of automatically changing the view, you could just check the orientation and change based on that.

Comment: @user1426865 - You could change presentModalViewController to pushViewController. That might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect orientation using:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(detectOrientation) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

then you can write a function to segue to the new ViewController when you detect a change:

```
-(void) detectOrientation {

    if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
    {
        if(!self->wasInLandscape)
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Landscape Segue" sender:self];
            self->wasInLandscape = YES;
        }


    } else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {

        if(self->wasInLandscape)
        {
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            self->wasInLandscape = NO;
        }

    }   
}
```

With this I set up the segue as a modal segue without animation so it just presents itself when you switch.  The `wasInLandscape` `BOOL` is used to make sure we don't dismiss or perform segues when we are already in the current position.